# Auto Scroll in an empty field during validation in flutter

Tags: forms, validation, flutter, dart, focus

I have created a form in flutter and during validation (when clicking on the button) I want it to scroll up to the empty field. I have tried many ways including FocusNode and because there are many textfields, its not working. I think I am doing it the wrong way. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

create a diffrent focusNode for each TextFormField and then
call requestFocus() on the Node when the validation is false.

first some where

```
final FocusNode d = FocusNode();
```

then in the TextFormField Widegt

```
focusNode: d
```

then in your validat

```
d.requestFocus();
```

and redo that for every TextField and not forget to check for the currect Text Field in the validator

Comment: I did that and it just keeps on going to the last two fields even after inputing it. Let me see how I can post my codes here so you can point it out where I am going wrong

Comment: please find the link, if you need anything else, please let me know:
https://github.com/shabeenabarde/signup/blob/master/signup.dart